# How to replace myproduct.exe with renamed eclipsec.exe

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, equinox

I have an Eclipse RCP product.

I am (ab?)using the p2.inf file, located in the directory the .product file is located in, to remove the .exe file and rename the eclipsec.exe file to the .exe file. The content looks as follows:

```
instructions.configure = \
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.copy(source:${installFolder}/eclipsec.exe, target:${installFolder}/myproductname.exe, overwrite:true);\
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove(path:${installFolder}/eclipsec.exe);
```

I need to build this product for windows and linux with maven tycho. For windows the p2.inf file instructions work fine. For linux this fails, which I am not surprised about (there is no .exe file).

Is there a way to execute those instructions for windows only / ignore the p2.inf file for linux builds when the product is built with tycho (for linux just 1 executable is generated anyway)?

Thanks in advance.

Tycho version: 1.0.0
Eclipse SDK version: 4.7.0

Comment: I don’t think the [`instructions.configure` property](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_customizing_metadata.html) allows you to be OS-dependent, as its possible for the [`root.*` properties](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_rootfiles.htm), but maybe rootfiles come in handy some other time for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How I moved eclipsec.exe to myproduct.exe (overwritten) without destroying the linux build

I added a *myproduct.p2.inf* file next to my *myproduct.product* file with the following content:

```
instructions.configure = \
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.copy(source:${installFolder}/eclipsec.exe, target:${installFolder}/myproduct.exe, overwrite:true);\
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove(path:${installFolder}/eclipsec.exe);\
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove(path:${installFolder}/../../../../linux/gtk/x86_64/myproduct/myproduct.exe);
```

With this state the copy instruction will fail for Linux builds because there is no *eclipsec.exe* file (FileNotFoundException). It's generated for Windows builds only.

Note that the copy instruction fails if specified files are not found while the remove instruction simply isn't executed in case the specified file does not exist.

### Workaround

To work around this problem I added the empty file *org.example.feature/filesToCopy/eclipsec.exe* to my feature (which is included in my feature based product) and added the line `root.linux.gtk.x86_64=filesToCopy` to the *build.properties* of the feature project. This copies the empty *eclipsec.exe* file to the Linux build.

**What happens for Windows:**

1. The product is built with *eclipsec.exe* and *myproduct.exe*
2. *eclipsec.exe* is copied to *myproduct.exe* (which overrides *myproduct.exe*)
3. *eclipsec.exe* is deleted

--> *myproduct.exe* is the only executable (next to the *myproduct.ini* file). All brandings are lost though!

**What happens for Linux:**

1. The product is built with the *myproduct* executable and an empty *eclipsec.exe* file.
2. *eclipsec.exe* is copied to *myproduct.exe*
3. *eclipsec.exe* is deleted
4. *myproduct.exe* is deleted too

--> The linux archive looks exactly as it was built by tycho. All the copying and renaming of *.exe files have no other purpose than making it possible to execute the copy instruction in the *p2.inf* file which is required for the Windows build.

Comment: That sounds like a hack. Have you tested if this works when a user makes a revert in the installation history?

Comment: Yeah, it's some kind of hack indeed. If I understand your question correctly: The user won't have access on an installation history. The product ist just a command line tool. When built with maven the following happens in the package phase: We materialize it, we apply the hack, we create an archive (tycho-p2-director-plugin). The built archive is shipped to the user.
For now this works fine so I stopped putting further effort into this. If this leads to problems at some time (which I currently cannot imagine yet), I'll try to go the way you suggested in your answer again.

Comment: Okay, I see. (Even if hardly anyone does, also [the installation history of a command line application can be reverted](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Revert_an_Update_or_Installation_with_p2).)

Comment: I didn't know that but when I wrote my comment above, I already suspected you that you'll correct me again^^. It seems there's always a way. But yea, as you said, the risk that someone will do / try that, is very low.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done either:

- with a **fragment** that contains the `p2.inf` file and that has the ***Platform Filter:* `(osgi.os=linux)`** or
- by defining an installation unit (IU) [similar to the example described here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=253244#c38) that contains a line like `units.0.filter=(osgi.os=linux)`. (see also *Customizing Metadata* in [Eclipse help](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_customizing_metadata.html) and in the [Eclipse wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Customizing_Metadata))

If possible, the first option is preferable, since the second option is more complex and requires more knowledge about p2.

Note, your root problem seems to be [Eclipse bug 185205](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=185205). Maybe you'd like to vote for it or comment on it. I suspect there is a better workaround than do a copy via p2 for that.

Comment: According to https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Customizing_Metadata p2.inf files can be located in bundles, features and products. Are you sure it's possible to have fragments with p2.inf?

Comment: A p2 repository consists of a metadata repository (`content.xml` or `content.jar`) and an artifact repository (`artifacts.xml` or `artifacts.jar`, the bundle JARs etc.). The `p2.inf` file contains instructions for the metadata repository only. In my understanding, the `p2.inf` file is only read when creating the update site (p2 repository). Only an installation unit can have a filter, not commands/instructions. Because a fragment becomes an installation unit in p2, I guess it will work. You can search in `content.xml` or `content.jar` for `eclipsec.exe` to check if it works.

Comment: I have no updatesite at all. I only have a product and a feature. The p2.inf file is read when the product is built with tycho.

Comment: That doesn't matter. If you build a product (e. g. with Tycho), a temporary p2 repository is created as an intermediate step and at the end the profile which corresponds to the metadata repository (zipped as `p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/<profile name>/<timestamp>.profile.gz`) contains the touchpoint instructions (both, the already executed and the instructions that have to be executed on update (when the old version will be uninstalled). Also, a `META-INF/p2.inf` file in a fragment works. I just tried it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have to solve it myself, posting complete solution here using windows filter.

Create file p2.inf in the "Product" project of your application
(or feature project).

Change MYPRODUCT to your own branding name.

When copying make sure there are no trailing spaces after backslashes in touchpoint actions or it won't work.

```
#create a requirement on the fragment we are creating
requires.22.namespace=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu
requires.22.name=MYPRODUCT.eclipsecoverride.config.win32.win32.x86_64
requires.22.range=[$version$,$version$]
requires.22.greedy=true
requires.22.filter=(osgi.os=win32)

#create a IU fragment with touchpoint action
units.0.id = MYPRODUCT.eclipsecoverride.config.win32.win32.x86_64
units.0.version = $version$
units.0.provides.1.namespace=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu
units.0.provides.1.name=MYPRODUCT.eclipsecoverride.config.win32.win32.x86_64
units.0.provides.1.version=$version$
units.0.filter=(osgi.os=win32)
units.0.instructions.configure = \
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.copy(\
source:${installFolder}/eclipsec.exe,\
target:${installFolder}/MYPRODUCT_console.exe,overwrite:true);\
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove(\
path:${installFolder}/eclipsec.exe);
```